# Is there any way I can get why a target is dropped in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, target

I dump targets using this

```
curl http://<prom_ip>:9090/api/v1/targets
```

I see some of the jobs are dropped. I even turned on debug logs in Prometheus - it still does not tell me why it is dropped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any [`relabel_config`s](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/mrVa9fnZPc8). I'm pretty sure that's the only way targets can be dropped.